# pgfplot function plotting

Tags: pgfplots

I want to draw a function using pgfplot. How it selects where to calculate the function? In the first range, it does not calculate at all.

```
\documentclass[article]{standalone}               
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
font=\large,
line width=1pt,
tick style={line width=0.8pt}}}
% Preamble: \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=newest}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=0.2, % x scale
        ymin=0, ymax=1, % y scale
]
\addplot{1/
(
(1e9
*x/11.778)
*3.273e-8
-3.273e-8 +1
)
};
\addplot coordinates{
(.125, .744)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=1, % x scale
        ymin=0, ymax=1, % y scale
]
\addplot{1/
(
(1e9
*x/11.778)
*3.273e-8
-3.273e-8 +1
)
};
\addplot coordinates{
(.125, .744)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is not clear for me. The first plot differs because of an other x limitation = 0.2. What kind of result you want to achieve, could you provide an image?

Comment: if you add `domain=0:1` to axis preambles, do you obtain what you like?

Comment: I think his problem is that the function value seems evaluated only in two places which are then connected by straight lines instead of drawing the function as a curve. In that case, add `[samples=200]` (or some other high number) to addplot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect, that you like to have one of the following plots:

[image]

for them i define `domain = 0:1`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15,
    every axis/.append style={
            font=\large,
            line width=1pt,
            tick style={line width=0.8pt}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=0.2, % x scale
        ymin=0, ymax=1, % y scale
        domain=0:1,  % added, key improvements
]
\addplot    {1/(1e9*x/11.778*3.273e-8 - 3.273e-8 + 1)};
\addplot    coordinates{(.125, .744)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=1, % x scale
        ymin=0, ymax=1, % y scale
        domain=0:1   % added, key improvements
]
\addplot    {1/((1e9*x/11.778)*3.273e-8-3.273e-8+1)};
\addplot    coordinates{(.125, .744)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=0.2, % x scale
        ymin=0, ymax=1, % y scale
        domain=0:1,% added, key improvements
        xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed},% formattin ticks' labels
]
\addplot [blue,no marks]    {1/(1e9*x/11.778*3.273e-8 - 3.273e-8 + 1)};
\addplot [red,mark=square*] coordinates{(.125, .744)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=1, % x scale
        ymin=0, ymax=1, % y scale
        domain=0:1   % added, key improvements
]
\addplot [blue,no marks]    {1/((1e9*x/11.778)*3.273e-8-3.273e-8+1)};
\addplot [red,mark=square*] coordinates{(.125, .744)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

`xmin` and/or `xmax` only defines which part will be displayed. The range where the function will be calculated is defined by `domain` and the number of calculation points is set by `samples`.

The default values are `domain=-5:5` and `samples=25`. So the function is calculated at the x-values `-60/12`, `-55\12`, `-50/12`, ..., `-5\12`, `0`, `5/12`, ..., `50/12`, `55/12`, `60/12` by default.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% <- set a compat!

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
font=\large,width=20cm,
line width=1pt,
tick style={line width=0.8pt},
xtick={-5,5},
minor x tick num=23,
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
extra x tick style={grid=none}
}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=-8, xmax=8, % displayed x range
        extra x ticks={-8,0,8}
]
\addplot+[only marks]{1/
(
(1e9
*x/11.778)
*3.273e-8
-3.273e-8 +1
)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=1, % x scale
        ymin=0, ymax=1, % y scale
        extra x ticks={0,.2,...,1}
]
\addplot{1/
(
(1e9
*x/11.778)
*3.273e-8
-3.273e-8 +1
)
};
\addplot coordinates{
(.125, .744)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you change only `domain` the values of `xmin` and `xmax` will be adjusted:

```
\documentclass[margin=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% <- set a compat!

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
font=\large,%width=20cm,
line width=1pt,
tick style={line width=0.8pt}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=6, % displayed x range
        ymin=0, ymax=1, % displayed y range
]
\addplot{1/
(
(1e9
*x/11.778)
*3.273e-8
-3.273e-8 +1
)
};
\addplot coordinates{
(.125, .744)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=6, % displayed x range
        ymin=0, ymax=1, % displayed y range
        domain=0:6% calculation range
]
\addplot{1/
(
(1e9
*x/11.778)
*3.273e-8
-3.273e-8 +1
)
};
\addplot coordinates{
(.125, .744)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        %xmin=0, xmax=6, % displayed x range
        ymin=0, ymax=1, % displayed y range
        domain=0:6% calculation range
]
\addplot{1/
(
(1e9
*x/11.778)
*3.273e-8
-3.273e-8 +1
)
};
\addplot coordinates{
(.125, .744)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]